# Запросы пользователей к MySQL из Java

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, jdbc, users

Здравствуйте.

Создаю игру на java, к ней хочу сделать БД (MySQL), где будет храниться вся информация о пользователях. Но это информация должна добавляться сама, при различных событиях, генерируемых пользователями: создание аккаунта, смена пароля, список созданных персонажей и т.д. Так как реализовать безопасный доступ к моей БД обычным игрокам? Создавать новых пользователей для MySQL? (Нужен хотя бы просто алгоритм, направление, куда думать, без кода).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не нужно давать доступ игрокам в MySQL. Пользователь MySQL должен быть один: это Ваше приложение.

Место для реализации безопасности зависит от того, как устроено приложение.
Если это веб-приложение то у него должна быть своя система авторизации.

Если дектопное или мобильное, то оно должно подключаться по HTTPS к серверу, слать запрос (REST, JSON), и уже сервер должен ходить в MySQL.

Никогда не публикуйте протокол MySQL наружу, никогда не давайте пользователям право прямо туда ходить, и не светите структуры таблиц.